# Does anyone have the Custom Post Permalinks plugin from John P. Bloch?

Tags: plugins, posts, customization, permalinks

Can you upload it somewhere or send to my email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still find the most recent version in [WordPress.org's plugin Subversion](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/custom-post-permalinks/tags/1.1.4/).

Comment: You rock!!!!!!!